# css column taking more space than needed

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working on a page in React and am facing something strange in a grid layout.

I create a 2 columns grid with many items, with some spanning 2 columns. I'm using a grid because I want some buttons (here, the yellow squares) to be aligned.

The issue is that the first column takes much more space than is needed: I am expecting the space to the left and the right of the buttons group to be the same.

The issue is visible in this simplified screen capture, where the space to the left of the "yyy" line is wider than to the right:

[image: grid screen capture]

The longer the first line text, the worst this gets.

There is no problem if the 'xxx' text doesn't wrap.

I cannot create a grid containing only the buttons, as in the real application, text, buttons and some other items interleave randomly.

I do not want to use fixed widths.

What is going on, how can I make sure the "xxx" text doesn't affect the grid layout this way?

This is the simplified React code corresponding to this screen capture:

```
          <div style={{ width: '360px' }}>
            <div
              style={{
                display: 'grid',
                gridTemplateColumns: 'auto auto',
                placeContent: 'center',
                placeItems: 'center',
                gap: '0.75rem',
                border: '1px solid red',
                fontSize: '16px',
                lineHeight: '1.5',
                // textAlign: 'center',
                fontFamily: 'Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, ui-sans-serif, system-ui',
              }}
            >
              <div
                style={{
                  gridColumnStart: '1',
                  gridColumn: 'span 2 / span 2',
                  border: '1px solid green',
                }}
              >
                xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xx
              </div>

              <div
                style={{
                  width: '1.75rem',
                  height: '1.75rem',
                  justifySelf: 'end',
                  gridColumnStart: 1,
                  border: '1px solid purple',
                  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                }}
              />
              <div
                style={{
                  justifySelf: 'start',
                  border: '1px solid purple',
                }}
              >
                yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy
              </div>

              <div
                style={{
                  width: '1.75rem',
                  height: '1.75rem',
                  justifySelf: 'end',
                  gridColumnStart: 1,
                  border: '1px solid purple',
                  backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                }}
              />
              <div
                style={{
                  justifySelf: 'start',
                  border: '1px solid purple',
                }}
              >
                zzz zzz
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
```

**Edit 12/27**

Adding a code [sandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-jepsen-r762qi?file=/src/index.js).

With this, you can see that the text's second line conditions the grid left column width.

**Edit 01/05**

I have tried with different browsers, this behaviour is the same for all of them, so it seems to be linked to the css grid specs, and how spacing is computed. Any thought anyone? Thanks!

**Edit 01/22**
Adding a drawing to clarify which spaces should be the same:
[image]

**Solution 01/24**
As was answered, the solution is to make a 4 columns grid, not 2.
The `gridTemplateColumns: 'auto auto auto auto'` solution is not 100% on target, as the yyy line still wrap sooner than it should:

[image: auto template wrapping]

But changing that to `gridTemplateColumns: '1fr auto auto 1fr'` seems to achieve the goal:

[image]

Below is the simplified React code, with the **solution**:

```
<div style={{ width: '360px' }}>
  <div
    style={{
      display: 'grid',
      gridTemplateColumns: '1fr auto auto 1fr', // 4 columns
      placeContent: 'center',
      placeItems: 'center',
      gap: '0.75rem',
      border: '1px solid red',
      fontSize: '16px',
      lineHeight: '1.5',
      // textAlign: 'center',
      fontFamily: 'Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, ui-sans-serif, system-ui',
    }}
  >
    <div
      style={{
        gridColumnStart: '1',
        gridColumn: 'span 4', // Text spans 4 columns
        border: '1px solid green',
      }}
    >
      xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xx
    </div>

    <div
      style={{
        width: '1.75rem',
        height: '1.75rem',
        justifySelf: 'end',
        gridColumnStart: 2, // Button & label use the center 2 columns
        border: '1px solid purple',
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      }}
    />
    <div
      style={{
        justifySelf: 'start',
        border: '1px solid purple',
      }}
    >
      yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy
    </div>

    <div
      style={{
        width: '1.75rem',
        height: '1.75rem',
        justifySelf: 'end',
        gridColumnStart: 2,
        border: '1px solid purple',
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      }}
    />
    <div
      style={{
        justifySelf: 'start',
        border: '1px solid purple',
      }}
    >
      zzz zzz
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a sandbox ?

Comment: You *are* using fixed width for the buttons though. Can't you use fixed width for the button column?

Comment: If I set the first column to a fixed width, then it is stuck to the very left, and the second column takes all remaining space (see sandbox)

Comment: not an expert here, but the cause of that strange behavior is actually because the middle split of grid is based on the `max-content`, and that first row of yours is the `max-content` in this case, you can see that it will be balanced if you add `white-space: nowrap` to the first row (but it will overflow). Imo, the easiest way to do this is by moving the first row to outside of grid, so that its content wouldn't become the `max-content`.

Comment: Thanks @Damzaky. Unfortunately this is a mush simplified version of the real application. In the real case, text fields, buttons etc... interleave. All these items have to stay within the same grid, but the buttons need to nicely align. So this is not really an option.

Comment: @Will59 does the solution you're seeking have to be using grid? Or is it fine with other methods (e.g. flexbox)?

Comment: @Damzaky it has to be a grid, or the buttons will not be aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the only way to get the layout that you want is a little tricky.

It involves creating 2 additional columns, ont the left and right of the existing ones.

Only the first element occupies the 4 columns.

The remaining ocuppy the second and the third:

```css
#container {
    width: 360px;
}

#grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    place-content: center;
    place-items: center;
    gap: 0.75rem;
    border: solid 1px red;
    
}

#first {
    grid-column: span 4;
    border: solid 1px green;
}

.btn {
    width: 1.75rem;
    height: 1.75rem;
    justify-self: end;
    border: solid 1px purple;
    background-color: yellow;
    grid-column: 2;
}

.txt {
    justify-self: start;
  border: solid 1px purple;
  font-size: 16px;
      grid-column: 3;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="grid">
<div id="first">xxxx xxx xxxx xxx xxx xxx xxx xxxx xx xxx xx xxxx xxxxx</div>
<div class="btn"></div>
<div class="txt">yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyyyy yyy</div>
<div class="btn"></div>
<div class="txt">zzzz</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Trying to explain where is the problem in the original layout:

1. Once the elements that ocupy only 1 column have set the width of their column
2. And the grid has still free space
3. and there is some element that ocupies more than 1 column

Then this element will make these columns grow. Given that it can make grow any of the columns, it will usually grow the smallest one, since this seems the more aestethic solution.

Comment: this is an amazing solution that I didn't think of and I still try to understand what happened, although it seems like the second row's `yyy` creates a new line even though it  seems to still have space for that (seems like the ghost columns somehow have some weird auto values). Nevertheless, I think this should be the accepted answer

Comment: oh I think I got it, seems like the ghost columns took the `min-content` (which in this case is the yellow box) as their width

Comment: Like Damzaky mentioned, this solution is not 100% there, as the "yyy" line doesn't take all the space it could, for some reason. Changing `grid-template-columns` to `1fr auto auto 1fr` does the trick though (as far as I could test). Thanks for this solution!

Comment: Happy that it helped!  I have added a little explanation about what was happening with the original layout

Answer (score 0):

Change `justifySelf: "start"` to `justifySelf: "stretch"`.

**justifySelf: "start"**
[image: justifySelf: "start"]

**justifySelf: "stretch"**
[image: justifySelf: "stretch"]

ps. [This article will be helpful to you](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I added a drawing to clarify which spaces I'm talking about; these should be the same. Thanks.

Comment: If you want equal distances from the edge, then try setting the grid to something like 1fr 5fr 5fr 1fr, and combine with grid-template-area as needed, where the 1fr around the edges is your padding. Unfortunately, someone lowered my reputation and I can not give a detailed answer (

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but this is not what I am looking for (no static size settings). If the button & "yyy" text need all the space, I want them to take it. But if, like here, they don't require it, I don't want all that space to the left of the button. Thanks for your feedback. Based on Damzaky's comment, I think there might be no way of doing this...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how it is done in React, but I would follow this logic:

1. Get the width of outer box (a). In your case, it is 360px (22.5rem)
2. Get the width of button (x). In your case, it is 1.75rem
3. Get the width of the div containing string (y). You may find out how many characters take up how much width, and set y accordingly.
4. Get the grid gap (z)
5. Estimate m = (a-x-y-z)/2
6. Grid widths should then be: x+m and y+m respectively
7. float the first grid's value to the right, the second to the left.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. One could effectively compute the overall layout, but the goal here is to let the browser do this by using the appropriate CSS. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. I marked with comments what should be removed and added.
Remove `place-content: center;` from `.grid`, add to cell with full width `width: 0; min-width:100%;`

```css
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    /* don't need */
    /* place-content: center; */
    place-items: center;
    gap: 0.75rem;
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, ui-sans-serif, system-ui;
}

.grid-cell-full-width{
    grid-column: span 2;
    border: 1px solid green;
    /* solution */
    width: 0;
    min-width:100%;
}

.grid-cell-yellow{
    width: 1.75rem;
    height: 1.75rem;
    justify-self: end;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    border: 1px solid purple;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.grid-cell-yellow-desc{
    justify-self: start;
    border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-cell-full-width">xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxx xxxxx</div>
    <div class="grid-cell-yellow"></div>
    <div class="grid-cell-yellow-desc">yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy yyy</div>
    <div class="grid-cell-yellow"></div>
    <div class="grid-cell-yellow-desc">zzz zzz</div>
</div>
```